# Deploy SQL Server and my dataBase with oneClick setup

Tags: sql-server

I'm asking if it's possible to deploy SQL Server and my database with oneClick setup.

I'm mean that I have to give to my client the setup file that contains my application and my database. The user should just have to click on the setup, and automatically install my application, SQL Server and deploy the database in one operation.

Is that possible?

---

Thanks but I 
need alos to know how to deply te SQL SERVER 2008 runTime?
I mean after installing the application, I have to instal the SQL Server and then deploy the database

Answer (score 0):

You can script all the objects in a database via the SSMS by right clicking on the db -> Tasks -> Generate Scripts -> Check Script All Objects in this database. Save the script to a .sql file and execute it against their SQL Server Instance.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible, your client just needs to provide SQL Server credentials during setup and your code can execute scripts during setup to create all the necessary database objects. If this doesn't fit your definition of "oneClick" than you would need to have this information ahead of time and include it in your installation but that would not be secure and it doesn't make much sense because you'd than have to create a unique setup for each client...

Comment: Thanks but I 
need alos to know how to deply te SQL SERVER 2008 runTime?
I mean after installing the application, I have to instal the SQL Server and then deploy the database